# RDLC- An Error occurred during local report processing. The report definition is not valid

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

I have a report form "Form1ReportSale". On it's load event I want to generate RDLC report on the basis of an ID which comes from another form. When I put my program in debug mode, DataSet returns expected value but throws an error.

Please find an attachment [image: Here is the error]

My "Form1ReortSale" load event code is following:

```
public partial class Form1ReportSale : Form
{
    string CS;
    private string id;
    public string UserID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public Form1ReportSale()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BikeDB"].ConnectionString;
    }

    private void Form1ReportSale_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        //DataSet1NewCustomerBike dsCustomers = GetData(id);
        reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"E:\Working Area\Directorate Of IT Project\Own Practices\BikeShowRoom\BikeShowRoom\Reports\Form1ReportSale.cs";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = getDataByID(Convert.ToInt32(id));
        ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1Customer",ds.Tables[0]);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

    private DataSet getDataByID(int ID)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM AddNewBike WHERE ID = '"+ID+"'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            con.Open();
            ad.Fill(ds);
        }
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the path that you have given:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"E:\Working Area\Directorate Of IT Project\Own Practices\BikeShowRoom\BikeShowRoom\Reports\Form1ReportSale.cs";
```

Form1ReportSale report extension should be .rdlc instead of .cs ... Copy the proper name which you have given to your report... or try this one

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "~/Reports/Form1ReportSale.rdlc";
```

Comment: I have change the path. Thanks but now i get an error `An error occured during local report processing`, `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportPrcoessingException:` This specified operation is not valid. Please help me out

Comment: Try this one ...if it doesnot work then tell me..reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Form1ReportSale.rdlc";

Comment: There was a problem in my datatable. As i run a query `select *` but i didn't set few fields in the dataTable. Anyhow thanks and i am marking your question